# Convert dictionary into array AND access one of the value Swift

Tags: swift

I have a dictionary - myDictionary - and I would like to convert it into an array in order to access the content of the array. I found that in a tutorial, but I think it didn't convert it because I cannot write print (values[2]).
Do you know how I can reach values[2] for example? It can be a random value of values, it doesn't matter.

```
var myDictionary:[String:Int] = ["Mohan":75, "Raghu":82, "John":79]
 
var keys = myDictionary.keys
var values = myDictionary.values
 
 
print("keys\n-------")
for key in keys {
   print("\(key)")
}
 
print("\nvalues\n-------")
for value in values {
   print("\(value)")
}
print (values[2])
```

Comment: You can convert your values to array by: `var values = Array(myDictionary.values)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values` is not an array, but `Array(values)` is. So then you can say `(Array(values))[2]`.

Comment: However, this would quite a silly thing to do, because `values` has no order. So which value is indexed as `2` will be random.

Comment: Well okay then! :)